# get_current_user_id() always return 0 in if else statement

Tags: functions, users, id

I'm trying to get logged in user id after if else statement but always return 0. When i put get_current_user_id() before it gives correct user id. How can I make it work in if statement?

```
<?php

function asd_endpt(){ 

//$user_id = get_current_user_id();
//echo $user_id; //<-- this returns user id


if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'])) { //Get Real IP
    $IP = $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'];
} else {
    $IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

if ($IP=="60.220.200.75" || $IP=="60.220.200.76") {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    echo $user_id; //<-- this always return 0
}
add_shortcode('asd_endpt','asd_endpt');
?>
```

Comment: What's the significance of those IPs? Is the issue that `get_current_user_id()` returns `0` inside an `if` statement, or that the user is not logged in when using those IPs? If you're connected with those IPs does WordPress otherwise show the user as being logged in?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jacob. Those IPs are from different servers wich sending a postback URL to my WordPress server (it's for security purposes). My code runs only when the user is logged in. Do you think I have to put something in if statement so get_current_user_id() can be accessed inside?

Comment: Why would there be a "current user" if they're postback requests? Did those servers 'log in' to the website?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this :( No, what I m trying to do is to credit my wp users when they completed some actions from those ips servers.

Comment: Well you won't be able to use `get_current_user_id()`, because those servers won't be logged in as that user. Those servers will need to send the user ID back to you, so that you can use that. If the postback includes `?user_id=1`, for example, you would check `$_GET['user_id']` instead.

Comment: Ah yes, I guess you right. I did put the userid key in URL parameters on my iframe. Thank you so much for your help.